# The proper way of developing child themes

Tags: wordpress

I am going to develop a child theme based on Canvas by WooThemes and I have one simple question: Since a lot can be configured from the theme admin panel, should I use that, rather than pure css in the child theme? For example, if I was to set the body background, should I do it like that, or would it be more recommended to write a single rule of css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can finish everything up in the theme panel, there's no need to write a child theme.

If you have other reasons for writing it, however, keep in mind that options (i.e., everything you do in the admin panel) will *not* transfer to other sites. Changes you make in the stylesheet will travel with your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Ah you know creating child theme is really good when you want to update your sites time to time.
When you want to make different version of the sites you can make child theme. Do whatever changes in your styles and push to update the theme.